# Trigger to Update Properties of a Parent Object in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers

I am trying to change the Background Color of the **ParentGrid** when the child control ( Button )  **ChildButton** is clicked

I want to achive this using Triggers but not sure if this is even possible

Please Suggest a way to DO this through XAML only

```
<Grid Name="ParentGrid" Background="Red">
            <Button Name="ChildButton" />
</Grid>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Grid Name="ParentGrid" Background="Red">
    <Button Name="ChildButton" Margin="100">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" 
        Storyboard.TargetName="ParentGrid" 
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="Blue"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```